How to add specific number of columns in VBA excel
Sub ColumnCount() 

Dim ColumnNumber As Long 
Dim Count As Integer 

ColumnNumber = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column 

Count = 25 - ColumnNumber 

End Sub

Now I want to add result of Count variable as columns after M column, how can I do it any help!

Is this what you are looking for? columns(columns("M").column+Count)

add result of Count variable as columns after M column Not sure what do you mean. So if count is let's say 5. You want to insert 5 columns after column M? If yes, then try this columns(14).Resize(ColumnSize:=CountOfCol).EntireColumn.Insert. Also avoid naming the variable as Count. Count is a property in Excel. I have used CountOfCol as an example.

So, you want to Insert a number of columns, after Column M.
Now, the Insert always adds to the left (or above).  There are two ways we can do that here: either start with Column N directly, or use an Offset on Column M:
Columns("M").Offset(0,1) 'Incomplete code, do not use

Next, we specify how many columns we want to be inserting, using Resize
Columns("M").Offset(0,1).Resize(,Count) 'Incomplete code, do not use

(Notice that we have an empty parameter in Resize — we don't want to change the number of rows, we we leave that blank and just type a comma to move on to specifying the Columns)
Finally, we want to do our actual Insert:
Columns("M").Offset(0,1).Resize(,Count).Insert 'Complete code!

